How to use Drupal rector to get started converting annotations to attributes?
Drupal Rector has a rule for converting annotations to attributes.
I wanted to run this rule on a local repo of the Key module to get started adding attributes.
So I installed Drupal Rector (composer require palantirnet/drupal-rector --dev) and copied the default config to the repo root (cp vendor/palantirnet/drupal-rector/rector.php).
Next, I ran Rector: vendor/bin/rector process dev/key
However, the annotation to attribute rule does not appear to be run (no attributes are generated from the annotations).
rector.php contains the Drupal 10 rule set:
    $rectorConfig->sets([
        Drupal8SetList::DRUPAL_8,
        Drupal9SetList::DRUPAL_9,
        Drupal10SetList::DRUPAL_10,
    ]);

and according to the docs, the annotation to attribute conversion is part of the Drupal 10 rules.
So what more do I need to do to execute this rector rule?

What does dev/key represent in the command call?

Oh, it's your local path to that module.

It's not immediately clear by looking at this vendor code that AnnotationToAttributeRector is actually part of those sets. Which documentation says that? https://github.com/palantirnet/drupal-rector/blob/main/docs/core_plugin_conversion.md explains how to convert plugin annotations (in core) but the rector.php file in that document is different than the default one you used. I am interested in the answer to this question.

@monalisa You are correct; although the Annotation to Attribute rule is listed in the "Drupal 10" category in the documentation, it is not part of the set DRUPAL_10 and needs to be enabled separately.  There are several gotchas with this so I'll tinker with it some more and then post an answer.

The annotations-to-attributes conversion is not included in a set; you have to enable it separately.
For example, add these lines to your rector.php:
   $rectorConfig->ruleWithConfiguration(\DrupalRector\Drupal10\Rector\Deprecation\AnnotationToAttributeRector::class, [

    // Setting both introduce and remove version to 10.x means the comments are not kept.
    // You need to specify each type of attribute you want to convert.
    new \DrupalRector\Drupal10\Rector\ValueObject\AnnotationToAttributeConfiguration('10.0.0', '10.0.0', 'ContentEntityType', 'Drupal\Core\Entity\Attribute\ContentEntityType'),
    new \DrupalRector\Drupal10\Rector\ValueObject\AnnotationToAttributeConfiguration('10.0.0', '10.0.0', 'ConfigEntityType', 'Drupal\Core\Entity\Attribute\ConfigEntityType'),
  ]);

With this, when you run rector process, all ConfigEntityType and ContentEntityType in your code will be converted from annotations to attributes.
Note that although this is an example from the docs (pointed out in a comment by @monalisa), this conversion has not yet happened in core, so the resulting code will break your site.
What if I want to convert other annotations to attributes?
As long as the attribute class exists, you can add a conversion as described above.  There's a giant meta issue on Drupal.org that lists which attributes are available and which still need work (core modules only).
In other words, this is not an automatic easy conversion; you have to choose the annotations you want to convert, and you need to ensure that core/the relevant contrib module already supports them; otherwise, you will generate bad code.
For example, to convert all blocks from annotations to attributes:
 $rectorConfig->ruleWithConfiguration(\DrupalRector\Drupal10\Rector\Deprecation\AnnotationToAttributeRector::class, [
    new \DrupalRector\Drupal10\Rector\ValueObject\AnnotationToAttributeConfiguration('10.0.0', '10.0.0', 'Block', 'Drupal\Core\Block\Attribute\Block'),
  ]);

This will give you output like this (git diff):
 /**
  * Provides a 'Datetime Testing' Block.
- *
- * @Block(
- *   id = "datetimetesting_block",
- *   admin_label = @Translation("Datetime testing block"),
- *   category = @Translation("Devel"),
- * )
  */
+#[KeyProvider(id: 'datetimetesting_block', admin_label: new \Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup('Datetime testing block'), category: new \Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup('Devel'))]

You can then run phpcs to clean up the formatting, but you will probably get Drupal.Arrays.Array.LongLineDeclaration because the array will be on a single line.  So you have to edit the output manually to break up the array into multiple lines (there is probably a way to get rector to do this cleanup?)
What if the Attribute class name is the same as a class that is already used?
The Rector rule won't do anything (it will fail to convert) silently.
For example, if you try to convert Constraints to attributes, it will fail because constraints have a use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint; and the rector rule can't handle this.
You can work around this by renaming the use statement like this:
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint as SymfonyConstraint;
And then running rector again; this time, it will do the conversion.
What if I want to convert an Annotation class to an Attribute class?
My interest in this rector rule was to generate an Attribute class from an Annotation class. However, that is not what the rule does; it converts an annotation of a class (in the comment at the top of the class) to an attribute (just above the class definition).  The conversion of /src/Annotation/MyClass.php to /src/Attribute/MyClass.php is something you have to do manually yourself.
